# Why no branch lengths on consensus trees?

Tags: r, phylogeny, r-ape

When making a consensus tree using `ape::consensus` the branch lengths are lost. Is there a way to not lose the branch lengths? Or to add them somehow to the consensus tree after making it.

```
library(ape)

> cat("owls(((Strix_aluco:4.2,Asio_otus:4.1):4.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);",     file = "ex1.tre", sep = "\n")
> cat("owls(((Strix_aluco:1.2,Asio_otus:4.5):3.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);",     file = "ex2.tre", sep = "\n")
> cat("owls(((Strix_aluco:3.2,Asio_otus:4.7):8.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);",     file = "ex3.tre", sep = "\n")
> tree1 <- read.tree("ex1.tre")
> tree2 <- read.tree("ex2.tre")
> tree3 <- read.tree("ex3.tre")
> trees <- c(tree1, tree2, tree3)
> trees_con <- consensus(trees)
> trees_con

Phylogenetic tree with 4 tips and 3 internal nodes.

Tip labels:
[1] "Strix_aluco"   "Asio_otus"     "Athene_noctua" "Tyto_alba"    

Rooted; no branch lengths.
```

Comment: [There is a discussion here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-phylo/2012-November/002432.html). There are opinions (see Joe Felsensteins' answer) that it does not make sense. However, his answer does not apply to strict consensus trees!! I think for **strict consensus trees** it does make perfect sense! Scott, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for the help on this! I don't think I solved this. I'll have a look at that discussion

Comment: Scott, and what about the [code of O'Meara](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-phylo/2012-November/002426.html)? Did it work for you? You replied that it's excellent and going to try it.

Comment: Scott, I would like to place a bounty on your question. But I need to rewrite it (restrict to strict consensus, because in general it is not possible) and provide a more general example (with different branches in different trees). Do you agree?

Comment: I will also add an expected result. I intend to make this perfect to get a perfect answer :-)

Comment: @Tomas Yes, your plan sounds good, please do